# Key remapping with modifier keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a US keyboard by I'm using a British keyboard layout.

The US keyboard doesn't physically have the keys <kbd>\</kbd> (backslash) and <kbd>|</kbd> (vertical bar).

I'd like to remap them to <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>#</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> respectively.

How can I achieve this?

I'm running Ubuntu Artful, which uses `xkb`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not crystal clear what you mean, but possibly you want to edit the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb` file and change the line

```
key <BKSL>  { [numbersign, asciitilde,   dead_grave,   dead_breve ] };
```

to

```
key <BKSL>  { [numbersign, asciitilde,    backslash,          bar ] };
```

Result:

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd> => \

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd> => |